# How to read geojson file using react?

Tags: reactjs

I am learning to react. I have fetched JSON file to read data and display it on google maps. But I am having issues reading geojson file in react and display polyglot on google maps. I have tried several methods. But I am failed in order to read and display polyglot on google maps. I have provided the link below Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

https://api.mevo.co.nz/public/home-zones/all

```
import './App.css';
import { 
  GoogleMap, 
  withScriptjs, 
  withGoogleMap,
  Marker,
  InfoWindow
} from "react-google-maps";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function Map() {
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const [settings, setItem] = useState([null]);

  // this useEffect will run once
  // similar to componentDidMount()
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://api.mevo.co.nz/public/home-zones/all")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setItems(result);
        },
        // instead of a catch() block so that we don't swallow
        // exceptions from actual bugs in components.
        (error) => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setError(error);
        }
      )
  }, [])

  if (error) {
    return <div>Error: it is</div>;
  } else if (!isLoaded) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  } else {
    return (
      <GoogleMap 
      defaultZoom={14}
      defaultCenter={{ lat: -41.292757, lng: 174.790984 }}>
      
      {items.map(item => (
            <Marker 
              key={item.iconUrl}
              icon={item.iconUrl}
              position={{ 
                lat: parseFloat(item.position.latitude),
                lng: parseFloat(item.position.longitude)
              }}
              onClick={() => {
                setItem(item);
    
              }}
              />
      ))}
      
      {error && (
        <InfoWindow>
          <div>Vehicle details</div>
        </InfoWindow>
      )}
      </GoogleMap>
    );
  }
}
  
const WrappedMap = withScriptjs(withGoogleMap(Map));

export default function App() {
 return (
   <div className="header">
     <h1 className="title">Welcome to my application!</h1>
   <div className="map" style={{ width: '100vw', height: '80vh'}}>
    <WrappedMap googleMapURL={`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places&key=${
      process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_KEY
    }`}
    loadingElement={<div style={{ height: "100%" }} />}
    containerElement={<div style={{ height: "100%" }} />}
    mapElement={<div style={{ height: "100%" }} />}
    />
  </div>
  </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: The returned JSON object doesn't have an array until you reference a few levels into it. I.e. if you `setItems(result);` then when you map state it would be something like `items.data.geometry.coordinates.map`. Also, there ins't any data in that endpoint's response data that has any objects with `iconUrl` or `position` properties to even map. Are you sure you've the correct API endpoint?

Comment: Hi Drew, thanks for the comment, I was using a different API to get iconUrl or position . I have tried items.data.geometry.coordinates.map as well. But it didn't work. This is the API  I have used to get iconUrl and position. I have provided a link to that api.  https://api.mevo.co.nz/public/vehicles/all

Comment: `{items.data.geometry.coordinates.map(item => ( <Marker position={{  lat: item[1][1], lng: item[0][0] }} />
  ))}`

Comment: Ok, with the returned JSON value from that new endpoint I don't see anything wrong with how you are processing the received data, state update, and mapping `items`. What specifically is the issue? Is there an error? What part isn't working as expected?

Comment: Hi @DrewReese, It shows TypeError: Cannot read property 'geometry' of undefined

Comment: Where though? Your code isn't attempting to access any `geometry` property.

Comment: @DrewReese, I think that problem is in this line `items.data.geometry.coordinates.map`

Comment: Sorry, can you include in your question the relevant code where you are doing `items.data.geometry.coordinates.map` then?

Comment: @DrewReese, that's what you meant by relevant code `{items.data.geometry.coordinates.map(item => ( <Marker position={{  lat: item[1][1], lng: item[0][0] }} />   ))}`

Comment: @DrewReese, if I put the comments on `{items.data.geometry.coordinates.map` on function. Map loads successfully. But of course, it does not show markers on the map

Comment: OK. Which data source are you trying to use? One has a `geometry` property but doesn't include any image URLs or position properties, other has image URLs and positions, but no geometry coordinates. Which is the one you need? FYI, if you look in the source code in the repo it seems nothing needs any geometries. It seems the data source with a geometry property doesn't have the marker data.

Comment: @DrewReese, this is URL https://api.mevo.co.nz/public/home-zones/all

Comment: @DrewReese, if you can please check out this page got more info about the API. Please check out this https://developer.mevo.co.nz/docs/public/home-zones

Comment: @DrewReese, I followed this tutorial yesterday to solve the problem. I was unsuccessful https://medium.com/@dmw9400/using-geojson-with-google-maps-api-5127f7498a33

Comment: I think you're mixing up data sources. The home-zones is a set of polygon zone coordinates. If you want to convert those to an array of positions then you'll need something like `items.data.geometry.coordinates..flat().map(([lat, lng]) => ...`. I'll take a look at the blog when I can try to get a bit more context about what you are trying to do.

Comment: @DrewReese, Sorry for the confusion I am using this URL https://api.mevo.co.nz/public/vehicles/all to draw latitude and longitude. I want to use this URL https://api.mevo.co.nz/public/home-zones/all to draw a polygon on the google map. I hope that you understand what I am trying to accomplish. Thanks!

Comment: I've successfully drawn vehicle pins using this URL https://api.mevo.co.nz/public/vehicles/all Second challenge is that I want to draw a polygon on the google map using https://api.mevo.co.nz/public/home-zones/all

Comment: Point of clarification: there is no JSON file here. JSON is a string format for transmitting data. While you can save this string to a file and read it later, that is not what youa re doing here. Rather you are fetching data in the JSON format from a URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you just need to also fetch and map the geofencing data. The `Polygon` component from `react-google-maps` appears to be *the* component to do this.

1. Import `Polygon` from  `react-google-maps`
2. Add `zones` state
3. Request the zone data and process response
4. Map `zones` to `Polygon` components

Updated code:

```
import './App.css';
import { 
  GoogleMap, 
  withScriptjs, 
  withGoogleMap,
  Marker,
  Polygon, // <-- import Polygon component
  InfoWindow
} from "react-google-maps";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function Map() {
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const [zones, setZones] = useState([]); // <-- add zones state
  const [settings, setItem] = useState([null]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // load up both requests in an array of promises
    Promise.all([
      "https://api.mevo.co.nz/public/vehicles/all",
      "https://api.mevo.co.nz/public/home-zones/all",
    ].map(url => fetch(url).then((res) => res.json()))
      ).then(
      ([markers, geoJSON]) => {
        setIsLoaded(true);
        setItems(markers); // <-- set markers state
        setZones( // <-- set zones state, map arrays to coordinate objects
          geoJSON.data.geometry.coordinates.map((zone) =>
            zone.map(([lng, lat]) => ({ lat, lng })) // <-- destructure lng then lat!!
          )
        );
      },
      // instead of a catch() block so that we don't swallow
      // exceptions from actual bugs in components.
      (error) => {
        setIsLoaded(true);
        setError(error);
      }
    );
  }, []);

  if (error) {
    return <div>Error: it is</div>;
  } else if (!isLoaded) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  } else {
    return (
      <GoogleMap
        defaultZoom={14}
        defaultCenter={{ lat: -41.292757, lng: 174.790984 }}
      >
        {items.map((item) => (
          <Marker
            key={item.iconUrl}
            icon={item.iconUrl}
            position={{
              lat: parseFloat(item.position.latitude),
              lng: parseFloat(item.position.longitude)
            }}
            onClick={() => {
              setItem(item);
            }}
          />
        ))}

        {zones.map((zone) => ( // <-- map the zones to Polygons
          <Polygon path={zone} />
        ))}

        ...
      </GoogleMap>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help! I really do appreciate it.

Comment: It is running without any errors, however, it does not draw a polygon on the google map. It seems to me that it is still not reading data from the URL. I have provided below. I am grateful for your help anyway. This is the URL, as you already know https://api.mevo.co.nz/public/home-zones/all

Comment: @GaganVirk If you can and don't mind, can you try creating a *running* codesandbox for this code? I suspect it is just a matter of converting the data format from mevo to what the google maps API wants. I can only speculate so far. With a running example then I can at least debug a little.

Comment: I have created a running sandbox for this code. Thank you so much for your help! This is the URL https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-solomon-h0lco

Comment: @GaganVirk Swap the lat and lng in the zone data mapping, i.e. `zone.map(([lng, lat]) => ({ lat, lng }))`. Interestingly enough that Medium article you linked also called this out, but since it wasn't clear to me what the data source was in that tutorial I didn't pass that detail along.

Comment: thanks for pointing out that to me. I have swapped with this code. But still sadly no success `let coordArr = [];
let coordinates = geoJSON.data.geometry.coordinates[0][0]
        setZones( 
          coordinates.map(coordinate =>
            coordArr.push({lat:coordinate[1], lng:coordinate[0]})
          )` I have made same changes in the sandbox as well. Thank you!

Comment: @GaganVirk It looks to be working from what I can tell, but perhaps I am not looking for the same specific thing you are. Try this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-read-geojson-file-using-react-p5hny). BTW, the zeroth zone appears to be an entire hemisphere, so you'd need to zoom out quite a bit to see it if that was the only zone being rendered.

Comment: @DrewResse, oh my god, I am overwhelmed with joy. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: @DrewResse can you please help me with one more little task? I want to zoom in when I click on vehicle pins. Can you please tell me that how can I implement onClick() inside the Marker tag? It want to do like map.setZoom(8). Thanks!

Comment: Other than using something like `const [zoom, setZoom] = useState(14);` and `defaultZoom={zoom}` on the map and `onClick={() => setZoom(8)}` on the Marker I probably can help much further. Looking in the docs I think the function you want is `panTo` which accepts a marker location, but don't see where/how `react-google-maps` exposes out that API.

Comment: thanks for the answer, you are right. I tried setZoom(8) inside onClick() in the Marker tag. It does not work. Cheers!

Comment: I am searching on google like how to use panTo in google maps react. But I couldn't find an answer. Thanks!

Comment: @GaganVirk Actually, just figured it out. Panning to a clicked marker, set the zoom to 16 since the default you are using is 14. Saved the updates the same last sandbox.

Comment: I really do appreciate your help! Thank you!!

Comment: where is the accepted option, So I can mark an answer as accepted. Thanks!

Comment: do you know how to render 3D buildings using google-map-react? I couldn't figure it out. I've accepted your answer.Thanks!!

Comment: I have created another sandbox for this.Thanks for your help! Please check out this link codesandbox.io/s/sad-cherry-lw8pf

Comment: @GaganVirk If you are referring to google map's "3-d buildings" I believe that occurs automagically when you zoom in enough. If you are referring to overlaying 3-d models then no, I don't know, sorry. Either way, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Point of clarification: there is no JSON file here. JSON is a string format for transmitting data. While you can save this string to a file and read it later, that is not what youa re doing here. Rather you are fetching data in the JSON format from a URL.

With that said, often the best place to start figuring out what to do with a JSON object or array is to `console.log()` it or use the browser's debugger to inspect the data. This will show you what we call the "shape" of the data. From there, you can figure out what code to write to acess the pieces of data from the JSON that you are interested in.